# Partitions Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Let $g(n,k)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts, in which no part is a $1$. Show that
$$g(n,k) = g(n-2,k-1) + g(n-k,k).$$

This was a problem for a counting and probability class I'm taking and I'm having difficulty proving this. It would be great if anyone could help :)

Comment: Check out this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342149/proving-a-partitions-problem-pn-k-pn-2-k-1-pn-k-k

Comment: **Please do not discuss this problem!**  This is an active homework problem.

To the original poster: I realize that homework may be challenging. If you wish to receive some help from the staff or other students, I encourage you to use the resources that the online classes provide, such as the Message Board.  Thanks.

Comment: @wonderman Should we delete our answers ?

Comment: @wonderman I'm not in an online class

Comment: **All** of your posts have been problems from taken from the same online class.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions of this type can be formed in two ways.

Either they have parts of size $2$ (as in the first diagram.) OR all their parts are greater than $2$ and can be formed by adding an extra row at the bottom of the representation of the partition  (as in the second diagram.)
[image]

Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(n,k)=g(n-2,k-1)+g(n-k,k).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Partitions of this sort are of two kinds :

1. those with at least a $2$, then the $k-1$ others must have sum $n-2$
2. those that don't contain a $2$, then you can substract $1$ to every number, you then have a sum $n-k$ to reach with the $k$ numbers.